# Serialized transaction doesn't seem to abort?

Tags: c#, transactions, transactionscope

I'm experimenting with serialized transactions, for example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)))
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, Transaction.Current);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        MemoryStream result = Second(stream);
        Transaction transaction = (Transaction)formatter.Deserialize(result);
        Console.WriteLine(transaction.TransactionInformation.Status);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static MemoryStream Second(MemoryStream stream)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Transaction transaction = (Transaction)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

    using (TransactionScope scope2 = new TransactionScope(transaction))
    {

    }

    Console.WriteLine(transaction.TransactionInformation.Status);

    MemoryStream newStream = new MemoryStream();
    formatter.Serialize(newStream, transaction);
    newStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return newStream;
}
```

But on both of the `WriteLines`, the transaction is reported as being Active for some reason. If I do the same thing without serialization, the behavior is as it should be (it aborts), but when I serialize it all of a sudden it stops behaving properly. What am I doing wrong?